# How to post using reverse in test Django

Tags: django

I have a test, where I try to update my post. In detailview I use pk for each posts.
How to send correctly pk in test? I try this but get an error.

test:

```
def test_if_user_can_update_news(self):
    self.client.login(username='test1', password='test1')
    news = News.objects.get(title='Test news')
    self.client.post(reverse('update_news', kwargs={
        'pk': news.pk,
        'title': 'Updated news'}))
    self.assertTrue(News.objects.filter(title='Updated news').exists())
```

error:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'update_news' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 1, 'title': 'Updated news'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['news/update_news/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/\\Z']
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
self.client.post(reverse('update_news', args=[news.pk]))
```

Comment: I need to send news.pk and fields that I want to change, in my situation it is title

Comment: is it `def update_news(request, pk, title)` ?

Comment: From what i see in your url, you only need pk. Could you show us the contains of `update_news` ?